# Parsing XML in DB using SQL. Getting display name as null also not able to get name="M_38517_KEY"

Tags: java, oracle

```
 <ModelDefinition version="6.0">
              <ClientName>BIC</ClientName>
              <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
              <DimensionName>ITEM</DimensionName>
              <JobLogId>1780752</JobLogId>
              <Specs>
                <Spec id="15495" name="BIC_18_MA">
                  <Model name="BIC_MARKET_ADVANTAGE" type="TSV" id="2237"/>
                </Spec>
              </Specs>
              <Dimension name="Product">
                <Folder name="MAUTO_18_CUSTOM_HIERARCHIES_MA_CSIA" ordernum="1"   visible="N" modelid="2237">
                  <Folder name="Lighters Hierarchies" ordernum="1" visible="Y">
                    <Hierarchy name="Lighters by Segment" type="Standard" ordernum="1">
                      <LevelGroups ordernum="1">
                        <LevelGroup name="CATEGORY" ordernum="1" visible="Y">
                          <DisplayName>CATEGORY_LTR_by_Segment</DisplayName>
                          <KeyColumns>
                            <Column name="M_38517_KEY"/>
                          </KeyColumns>
                         </LevelGroup>
                      </LevelGroups>
                    </Hierarchy>
               </Folder>
             </Folder>
            </Dimension>
            </ModelDefinition>
```

SELECT B.DISP_NAME FROM ITEM_XML_MODEL_AUTMN_TMP AD, XMLTABLE ('$d/ModelDefinition' PASSING XML_TX AS "d" COLUMNS ATTR_DET XMLTYPE PATH 'Dimension') A,
        XMLTABLE ('/Dimension'
                    PASSING A.ATTR_DET COLUMNS
                    DISP_NAME     VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '/Folder/Folder/Hierarchy/LevelGroups/LevelGroup/DisplayName'
                     ) B
                    WHERE AD.JOB_LOG_ID = 1
                      AND AD.SPEC_ID       = 111

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0):

2-nd xmltable is wrong.

```
 xmltable('/Dimension'
                   passing A.ATTR_DET
                   columns DISP_NAME varchar2(2000) path '/Folder/Folder/Hierarchy/LevelGroups/LevelGroup/DisplayName') B
```

Should be (start after dimension)

```
 xmltable('/Dimension/*'
                   passing A.ATTR_DET
                   columns DISP_NAME varchar2(2000) path '/Folder/Folder/Hierarchy/LevelGroups/LevelGroup/DisplayName') B
```

or (without the slash in the path) For me, this option is better.

```
 xmltable('/Dimension'
                   passing A.ATTR_DET
                   columns DISP_NAME varchar2(2000) path 'Folder/Folder/Hierarchy/LevelGroups/LevelGroup/DisplayName') B
```

Update for `expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence`.

Probably the element `LevelGroup` exists more than one time in XML. Check this query

```
xmltable('/Dimension/Folder/Folder/Hierarchy/LevelGroups/LevelGroup'
                   passing A.ATTR_DET
                   columns DISP_NAME varchar2(2000) path 'DisplayName') B
```

Comment: If I go for '/Dimension/*' getting null for 2nd option "'/Dimension'" getting "ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence
19279. 00000 -  "XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence" 
*Cause:    The XQuery sequence passed in had more than one item.
*Action:   Correct the XQuery expression to return a single item sequence.